# Defining a lot of attributes in a class

Tags: object-oriented, coding-standards

Suppose that you have to develop a program which stores the products with their features and perform some operations on them, and you decide to design a class to represent the products. Each product has 10 different features. Three of them are numeric values. The remains are string values.

In this case, do you prefer to define all string attributes one by one in one under another format or a string array with seven elements ? Which one is more conventional and more correct ?

I think taking 10 different attributes with constructor and assigning them into the attributes one by one seem very bad. If we utilize a string array to represent the attributes, we can perform assign operation with only one for loop, which seems more readable.

Comment: What are the chances that, over the lifetime of the software, you will need to add one or more additional attribute(s) for some product you haven't seen yet?  YMMV, but pretty good, I suspect, since you have 10 already; this suggests to me to consider a dynamic approach to the attributes.

Answer (score 5):

There are several options here to deal with the situation:

Say you have a product with the following attributes:

- name
- description
- id
- color
- size
- weight
- price
- categories
- brand_id
- sku

**0)** Setting them via constructor arguments

Independently what one might say about the number of arguments for a constructor, here the case is clear: we have a data object with its attributes and we have to deal with it. So using 10 arguments in a constructor is totally fine.

**1)** Some languages allow besides the typical *positional* parameters *named parameters*. So in python, you could write `Product(name="A shirt", color="red" ...)` which results in a readable constructor. And with indentation it doesn't look too overwhelming:

```
Product(name="A shirt",
        description="A cool shirt",
        id=1,
        color="red",
        size="XXL",
        weight=200,
        price="1000",
        categories=["shirt","clothes", "male"],
        brand_id="0987654321",
        sku="1234567890"
)
```

**2)** Using a `Dictionary` / `Associative array` / `HashMap`

You prefill a dictionary with key-value-pairs like `product["name"]="A shirt"` and when you initialize your instance, you pass the dictionary to the constructor. So it is clear, how each attribute is set. The problem of *getting the positional arguments in the right order* is circumvented.

Possible downside:

When your dictionary is missing important information, the error will be thrown at runtime, which could be late. If you are using a statically typed language, this kind of error could be omitted, if you used the type system instead of the weak dictionary construct.

**3)** Using a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) together with the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

You'll get something like:

```
Product(sku)
   .name("A Name")
   .description("Desc")
   ... 
   .build();
```

Especially, when not all attributes are necessary at creation time, you could have the necessary attributes set via constructor arguments and optional ones via fluent interfaces.

**4)** Sometimes it is possible to have semantic groups:

Say you are storing customer data, you could have a subclass `address`, which would encapsulate (`street`, `zip`, `city`) or `contactinformation` (`phone`, `mail`) which help breaking the constructor apart: `Person(firstname, lastname, address, contactinformation)` is more readable than `Person(firstname, lastname, street, zip, city, phone, mail)` and because of lesser parameters, even if you are bound to positional parameters easier to get the order right.

But with product attributes like above, I have to admit, it is hard, finding a group.

---

To your points:

> In this case, do you prefer to define all string attributes one by one in one under another format or a string array with seven elements ?

I prefer having meaningful names for parameters. Besides of getting the position wrong, you do not even know, what position in the array is what.

> I think taking 10 different attributes with constructor and assigning them into the attributes one by one seem very bad

Not per se. But if there are other possibilities, you might want to use them.

> we can perform assign operation with only one for loop, which seems more readable.

From the perspective of "what is going on" you do not have too much redundancy going on and the resulting code might be shorter. Agreed. But As I said, if someone (or maybe you in a year) has to deal with this code, one has to invest time to fill in the gaps. And the more redundant your code is, the less you have to fill in, the easier it is, to work with this code.

Answer (score 3):

The number of assignments or constructor parameters is not a sensible metric of how good your class is.

Your data model should be correct and useful. If your model has these ten attributes, then creating a class with ten attributes is probably the right approach.

Using an array would suggest that the values in the array don't have individual names, but are multiple ordered values for the *same* attribute. This could be a good approach if there are many optional features that a product either does or doesn't support. Listing a feature name in the array would then indicate that this feature is supported. However, this data model can be more difficult to use.

The more dynamic your data model is (e.g. hash tables instead of object members), the more fragile and difficult to reason about your application gets. On the extreme end of this are [Entity–Attribute–Value models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) that are completely dynamic. They are generally inappropriate except when the business domain cannot be modelled up front.

But in your case, you do have a model with these limited ten attributes, so the flexibility of a more dynamic model is probably unneeded, and likely counter-productive.

Comment: `Using an array would suggest that the values in the array don't have individual names`. Just another way to look at it. If you find that the order of the elements within the array matters, the array strategy is debatable. That would be similar to implementing a single string matching an aspecific pattern, where each position within the pattern supplies the value for a specific field. Good or bad I don't dare to say. But definitively, is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Those 10 different features, would they be the same features for each product? If so, you could use an extra class ProductFeatures. You may have basic features that each product has and special features that differ per product. This would call for an inheritance tree of product features or you could pass a BasicProductFeatures as the first argument to each product's constructor and add the special features as separate arguments.

Above all, think logical/model, stop letting your design decisions be determined by technical things. Like "A lot of arguments is bad, let me slap them together in some container, now I have one argument, hooray". If the container does not mean anything in your model, you made it worse.